# JSON with numbers parsing to model

Tags: java, json, gson

I would like to parse JSON data from a web service provider 
to model in my web service client. I have been trying to do this by using GSON library. The problem sounds simple but the JSON looks like this:

`{
  "aaData": [
    {
      "0": 23,
      "1": "København",
      "2": 1
    },
    {
      "0": 10,
      "1": "Esbjerg",
      "2": 2
    },
    {
      "0": 21,
      "1": "Glostrup",
      "2": 3
    },
    {
      "0": 19,
      "1": "Helsingør",
      "2": 4
    },
    {
      "0": 7,
      "1": "Herning",
      "2": 5
    },
    {
      "0": 18,
      "1": "Hillerød",
      "2": 6
    },
    {
      "0": "18A",
      "1": "Hillerød (Frederikssund)",
      "2": 7
    },
    {
      "0": 1,
      "1": "Hjørring",
      "2": 8
    },
    {
      "0": "1A",
      "1": "Hjørring (Frederikshavn)",
      "2": 9
    },
    {
      "0": "1B",
      "1": "Hjørring (Aabybro)",
      "2": 10
    },
    {
      "0": 16,
      "1": "Holbæk",
      "2": 11
    },
    {
      "0": "16A",
      "1": "Holbæk (Kalundborg)",
      "2": 12
    },
    {
      "0": 6,
      "1": "Holstebro",
      "2": 13
    },
    {
      "0": "6B",
      "1": "Holstebro (Thisted)",
      "2": 15
    },
    {
      "0": 8,
      "1": "Horsens",
      "2": 16
    },
    {
      "0": 9,
      "1": "Kolding",
      "2": 17
    },
    {
      "0": "9A",
      "1": "Kolding (Vejle)",
      "2": 19
    },
    {
      "0": 20,
      "1": "Lyngby",
      "2": 20
    },
    {
      "0": 14,
      "1": "Nykøbing Falster",
      "2": 21
    },
    {
      "0": "14A",
      "1": "Nykøbing Falster (Nakskov)",
      "2": 22
    },
    {
      "0": 15,
      "1": "Næstved",
      "2": 23
    },
    {
      "0": "15A",
      "1": "Næstved (Slagelse)",
      "2": 24
    },
    {
      "0": 12,
      "1": "Odense",
      "2": 25
    },
    {
      "0": 3,
      "1": "Randers",
      "2": 26
    },
    {
      "0": "3A",
      "1": "Randers (Grenaa)",
      "2": 27
    },
    {
      "0": 17,
      "1": "Roskilde",
      "2": 28
    },
    {
      "0": 13,
      "1": "Svendborg",
      "2": 29
    },
    {
      "0": 11,
      "1": "Sønderborg",
      "2": 30
    },
    {
      "0": "11C",
      "1": "Sønderborg (Haderslev)",
      "2": 31
    },
    {
      "0": "11A",
      "1": "Sønderborg (Tønder)",
      "2": 32
    },
    {
      "0": "11B",
      "1": "Sønderborg (Aabenraa)",
      "2": 33
    },
    {
      "0": 5,
      "1": "Viborg",
      "2": 34
    },
    {
      "0": "5A",
      "1": "Viborg (Silkeborg)",
      "2": 35
    },
    {
      "0": 2,
      "1": "Ålborg",
      "2": 36
    },
    {
      "0": 4,
      "1": "Århus",
      "2": 37
    },
    {
      "0": "4A",
      "1": "Århus (Samsø)",
      "2": 38
    },
    {
      "0": 24,
      "1": "Bornholm",
      "2": 39
    },
    {
      "0": 22,
      "1": "Frederiksberg",
      "2": 40
    },
    {
      "0": "22A",
      "1": "Frederiksberg (Howitzvej)",
      "2": 41
    }
  ]
}`

Soo the data model classes should look like this:

`public class AaData
{
    private String 2;

```
private String 1;

private String 0;

public String get2 ()
{
    return 2;
}

public void set2 (String 2)
{
    this.2 = 2;
}

public String get1 ()
{
    return 1;
}

public void set1 (String 1)
{
    this.1 = 1;
}

public String get0 ()
{
    return 0;
}

public void set0 (String 0)
{
    this.0 = 0;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [2 = "+2+", 1 = "+1+", 0 = "+0+"]";
}}
```

and

public class Jurisdictions
{
    private AaData[] aaData;

```
public AaData[] getAaData ()
{
    return aaData;
}

public void setAaData (AaData[] aaData)
{
    this.aaData = aaData;
}

@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "ClassPojo [aaData = "+aaData+"]";
}
```

}

So the problem is that Java exactly dont like name variables by numbers.
Any ideas in GSON ?
Maybe different library ?
Thanks !

Comment: This mapping looks nice for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this calls for the [`SerializedName`](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/annotations/SerializedName.html) annotation.

Instead of:

`private String 1;`

Use for example:

`@SerializedName("1") private final String fieldOne;`

Answer (score 0):

something like this might help you:

```
private Object extractJsonNodeValueBasedOnNodeType(final JsonNode jsonNode) {
    final JsonNodeType nodeType = jsonNode.getNodeType();
    final Object nodeValue;
    switch (nodeType) {
        case NUMBER:
            nodeValue = jsonNode.asLong();
            break;
        default:
            nodeValue = jsonNode.asText();
            break;
    }

    return nodeValue;
}
```